# eloquent javascript - Closure and Functions

Tags: javascript, function

In eloquent JavaScript, the author provides the following example + prose:

> With a slight change, we can turn the previous example into a way to
>   create functions that multiply by an arbitrary amount.

```
function multiplier(factor) {   
    return function(number) {
        return number * factor;   
    }; 
}

var twice = multiplier(2); 
console.log(twice(5)); 

// → 10 The explicit
```

> localVariable from the wrapValue example isn’t needed since a
>   parameter is itself a local variable.
>
> Thinking about programs like this takes some practice. A good mental
>   model is to think of the function keyword as “freezing” the code in
>   its body and wrapping it into a package (the function value). So when
>   you read return function(...) {...}, think of it as returning a handle
>   to a piece of computation, frozen for later use.
>
> In the example, multiplier returns a frozen chunk of code that gets
>   stored in the twice variable. The last line then calls the value in
>   this variable, causing the frozen code (return number * factor;) to be
>   activated. It still has access to the factor variable from the
>   multiplier call that created it, and in addition it gets access to the
>   argument passed when unfreezing it, 5, through its number parameter.

how does javascript know that the 5 in:

```
console.log(twice(5));
```

is suppose to be the value for number? Is JavaScript essentially saying to itself "I already have 2 as the value for factor, and I can't change that, so 5 has to be the value for number".

In other words

```
var twice = multiplier(2)

so twice =  multiplier(2) {return function (number)}

thus twice(5) = multiplier(2) {return function (5)}
```

Is this right?

if there was another local variable inside multiplier, could I call:

```
twice(5,10)
```

and javascript would know that means:

```
factor = 2
number = 5
third variable = 10
```

Answer (score 4):

**ES6 VERSION**

```
const multiplier = factor => {
  return number => number * factor;
}
```

The part that confused me was thinking that the variable 'twice' was being assigned the multiplier function, rather than the *return* of the multiplier function (which is also a function).

```
const twice = multiplier(2);
```

So what is actually being assigned is:

```
const twice = number => number * 2

twice(2)
-> 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as this :

```
var twice = function(number) {
        return number * 2;   
    };
```

When you call multiplier(2) you are creating a new function that embeds factor into that new function.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this for a bit as well. Here's what helped it click for me.

On the book's website, you can interact with the code on the page:

https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_O3ISvGjNhj

I tried removing the arguments from the **twice** variable:

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return number => number * factor;
}

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice);
```

This returned: number => number * factor

That helped me realize that **twice** is being assigned the inner function of **multiplier**. When I don't pass an argument, it returns the inner function itself. When I pass an argument to **twice**, it becomes the argument of that inner function, and executes it.

So when I tried this:

```
console.log(twice());
```

It attempted to *execute* the function. And it returns **NaN** because I didn't pass an argument for **number**.

So, when we do this:

```
let twice = multiplier(2);
```

We are binding the variable **twice** to the inner function of the **multiplier** function with (effectively) an argument of 2 passed.

The previous comments explained this operation much more succinctly, but it didn't quite make sense to me until this clicked.